# How to integrate plural payment gateway in ionic angular project

Tags: ionic-framework

my name is Vinay, and i try to integrate plural payment gateway in ionic angular project. but problem is how to install plural payment gateway in app. i don’t understand plural gateways documentation. before i use razor pay gateway but unfortunately its is stop working in India . new user can not register on razor pay
Similarly, I am not able to register on Paytm gateway as well.

please helm me if you know how to integrate plural payment gateway in ionic 6 project.

thank you in advance​ .